# IF string equals TEXT then IMAGECREATEFROMPNG

Tags: php, if-statement, imagecreatefrompng

I currently have a imagecreatefrompng function and it works, but when I use an IF statement on it, then it doesn't work and shows it cannot load image... here is what I have:

```
$design = $_GET["design"];

if ($design == "DESIGN_1") { $image = imagecreatefrompng('designs/hill.png'); }
if ($design == "DESIGN_2") { $image = imagecreatefrompng('designs/hill2.png'); }
```

---

---

In the header I have:

`http://www.website.com/create.png?design=DESIGN_1`

it displays the HILL.PNG

---

---

But when I have this following in header:

`http://www.website.com/create.png?design=DESIGN_2`

it doesn't display HILL2.PNG but shows the image not found symbol.

---

---

PS. Both images are in the designs folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you view the second `.png` in a browser if you navigate to it? Could it be a malformed image file? Since the code appears to be fine, and it's actually trying to display an image... I have to think that there's a problem with the image itself.

Comment: That image is working, all I did was copy the image and put a black stripe through it with an imaging editor and saved it as hill2.png and then uploaded it. I can navigate to it.. hmm.

Comment: Seems to work now, must have just been my cache holding back from loading hill2.png as before I tried and I didn't have the image hill2.png placed in the right folder, and then my cache didn't re-load. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The PHP code is OK.

Probably there's an error with the image "designs/hill2.png"

Check it with
    `<img src="http://www.website.com/designs/hill2.png"/>`

Comment: That image is working, all I did was copy the image and put a black stripe through it with an imaging editor and saved it as hill2.png and then uploaded it. I can navigate to it.. hmm.